# Mouseup event not getting triggered when component is dropped using React-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd, onmouseup

I am working on a project where I need to implement drag and drop functionality using React-dnd package. Which is I am able achieve. But the issues is, the target component (where draggable items will be dropped) contains *mouseup* event which is getting triggered in every scenarios except when I drop any component in it. It needs to be triggered even in the case of drop as well but its not getting triggered. I tried manual triggered as well and it triggered but the values like offsets are not as per expected.

I have share sample code sandbox where Dustbin.tsx contains that mouseup event which is not getting triggered when any draggable component is dropped into it. Thanks.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-snowflake-ej08d0?file=/src/Dustbin.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using `onmouseup`?

> The onmouseup event occurs when a user releases a mouse button over an element.

If you want to detect if something is dropped inside that container then please use `ondrop`

> Execute a JavaScript when a draggable element is dropped in a  element:

```
return (
    <div
      ref={drop}
      style={{ ...style, backgroundColor }}
      onDrop={() => console.log("dropped")}
    >
      {isActive ? "Release to drop" : "Drag a box here"}
    </div>
);
```